# Disable JAXB NameSpace ns1

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, namespaces

I have exposed one web service and getting below below output while receiving request from client and sending to another web serice without code changes. source system is not accepting the child level namespace, it is accepting only parent level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Travel111 xmlns="http://travel" xmlns:ns2="http://mycompany/train" xmlns:ns3="http://mycompany/passenger">
    <train>
        <ns2:Passengers>
            <ns2:Passenger>
                <ns3:TicketNumber>10000</ns3:TicketNumber>
            </ns2:Passenger>
            <ns2:Passenger>
                <ns3:TicketNumber>20000</ns3:TicketNumber>
            </ns2:Passenger>
        </ns2:Passengers>
    </train>
</Travel111>
```

I don't want Namespace attribute like ns2,ns3. I want below output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Travel111 xmlns="http://travel">
    <train xmlns="http://mycompany/train">
        <Passengers xmlns="http://mycompany/passenger" >
            <Passenger>
                <TicketNumber>10000<TicketNumber>
            </Passenger>
            <Passenger>
                <TicketNumber>20000</TicketNumber>
            </Passenger>
        </Passengers>
    </train>
</Travel111>
```

what i have to change in packe-info.java to get above output.

I am not doing marshelling by default it is done by spring web service while receive the request.
thanks in advance